# How to import data into Visual Studio 2012 Sql Server Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking at using Sql Server Database projects.  It appears to import schema and stored procedures from a database, but there's no mechanism to import actual data.  As part of our build process, we usually import both schema and data.

Can this be done from Sql Server Database projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current solution is to place reference data use a post-deployment script. The script must be written to be idempotent as it has no knowledge of the state of the target. This is described in detail here:

[Including Data in a SQL Server Database Project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/02/02/including-data-in-an-sql-server-database-project.aspx)